# Codesign failed

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Another of these questions...
But I don't think it's a verification problem, I believe.
I've been searching the forums. I'm building an App in Unity 3D. Usually works fine.
but when I archive my project to upload, I get "Codesign failed"

Looking through the logs I see Nothing in the CodesignResolver

only real problem I see is in the distributionStandard log:

> ```
> "<IDEDistributionIssue: severity(error), error(Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-20008 \"The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive.  Please make sure /var/folders/_k/9jd5s_9d1h59l72f3bfs018r0000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.PeC/Unity-iPhone.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive.\" UserInfo=0x7fce68a8e030 {NSLocalizedDescription=The package could not be unpacked because of the following error: Unable to extract archive.  Please make sure /var/folders/_k/9jd5s_9d1h59l72f3bfs018r0000gn/T/XCodeDistPipeline.PeC/Unity-iPhone.ipa is a valid zip or ipa archive., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.})>"
> ```
>
> )
>   2015-01-08 05:35:56 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant

And in the distributionVerbose there is this:

> 2015-01-08 05:35:29 +0000 [MT] -[IDEDistributionProvisioning _signingCertificatesApplicableForTeamID:certificateKind:isForInstaller:error:]: identityCertificatesMatchingKind [kind=1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] = (
>       ""
>   )

Thanks for your help!

~Be

Comment: Other Apps I build work fine